# Как отправить файл на сервер PHP из JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, сервер

Я новичек, поэтому не кидайтесь пожалуйста камнями))).

Не понимаю почему не отправляются данные из "file" в обработчик PHP.
С обработчика распечатываю любое значение и ответ приходит обратно в JS, но когда я пытаюсь распечатать "file" приходит пустой ответ.

Делаю я все это что бы убедится что файл улетает в обработчик, для того что бы этот файл потом записать в на сервер в папку

```js
// $(function () {
//     alert('Подключен form_mail.js');
// });

$("#sendMail").on("click", function() {
  let name = $("#name").val().trim();
  let email = $("#email").val().trim();
  let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
  let number_order = $("#number_order").val().trim();
  let message = $("#message").val().trim();
  let file = $("#file").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'assets/ajax/mail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'tel': tel,
      'number_order': number_order,
      'message': message,
      'file': file
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#sendMail").prop("disable", true);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
      alert(data);
      // if(data) {
      //     $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
      //     $("#sendMail").prop("disable", false);
      //         alert("Сообщение отправлено");
      // }else{
      //     alert("Ошибка");
      // }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_contact" action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-one__form">
  <!---->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-box">
        <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
        <input required type="text" id="name" placeholder="Иван Иванов" name="name" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-box">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input required type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-box">
        <label for="tel">Номер телефона</label>
        <input required type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="+79997772255" name="tel" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-box">
        <label for="number_order">№ заказа</label>
        <input required id="number_order" type="text" placeholder="0000000-я00" name="number_order" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="input-box">
        <label for="message">Сообщение</label>
        <textarea required id="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input id="file " type="file" name="file" value="">
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
      <br>
      <button type="button" id="sendMail" class="main-btn">Отправить</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.thm-btn contact-one__btn -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242067/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-php-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ajax-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8/1242142#1242142

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отправлять файл через FormData

```
$("#sendMail").on("click", function () {
    let name = $("#name").val().trim();
    let email = $("#email").val().trim();
    let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
    let number_order = $("#number_order").val().trim();
    let message = $("#message").val().trim();
    let file  = $("#file");

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('tel', tel);
    formData.append('number_order', number_order);
    formData.append('message', message);
    formData.append('file', file.prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/ajax/mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#sendMail").prop("disable", true);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
            alert(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Отправка вообще перестала работать, браузер ругается на processData: false, тогда я его закоментировал, так браузер начал последовательно ругаться далее на поэтапно на каждую строчку.

Comment: Правда это после того как я добавил     dataType: "html", а если брать чисто Ваш пример, то ругается на     formData.append('file', file.prop('files')[0]);

Comment: То есть ни как он не хочет отправлять файл в обработчик.

Comment: @Sirius_MkLain Что в консоле пишет?