# HTML форма не видит скрипт JQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в проблеме.
На локальной машине (XAMPP) пишу небольшой сайт. Есть страница PHP на которой написана форма с отправкой через скрипт JQuery. В написании скрипта сам не силен, поэтому взял из интернета и адаптировал под свои нужны. Но вся проблема в том, что при отправке формы сама форма не видит скрипт JQuery и просто пытается отправить форму через GET запрос, хотя я указываю POST.

Для проверки написал простейшую форму и обработчик. Скрипт брал из сети. Но даже эта форма пытается отправиться как GET. Насколько я понимаю, происходит это потому, что форма не видит скрипт и по умолчанию отправляет как GET.

UPD: ссылки на JQuery на странице подключены:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем ошибка.

HTML-форма:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="imp1" />
<button type="submit" name="ok">отправить</button>
</form>
```

Скрипт JQuery:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event) {

    $data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: "form1proc.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: $data, 
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data){ 
        
      }
    });
  });
```

Обработчик PHP:

```
$f1=$_POST['imp1'];
echo $f1;
```

Comment: Ну наверное не `type: "POST"`, а `method: "POST"`

Comment: @Simon, пробовал и так, и как Вы говорите. Но итог все тот же, не работает.

Comment: Я как-то писал уже скрипт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242067/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-php-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ajax-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8/1242142#1242142

Comment: @Николай, воспользовался Вашим вариантом - все отправляется отлично! Спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, если в форме передаются два файла в двух input, Ваш вариант скрипта будет работать?

Comment: Попробуйте, все зависит от того как передаете, и как получаете

Answer (score 2):

скрипт должен быть после формы, проверь

UPD: type: 'POST' не будет работать, как правильно заметил комментатор выше. надо написать method: 'POST'

также данные отправить в виде FormData

```
const data = new FormData(this);
```

вот что должно получиться

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event) {

  const $data = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
     url: "form1proc.php",
     method: "POST",
     data: $data, 
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(data){ 
    
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Да, так и есть. Скрипт в самом конце, после формы.

Comment: К сожалению, все так же. При нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит, запрос добавляется в адресную строку, как при GET запросе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, даже если у меня скрипт или обработчик некорректны, все равно должна же быть попытка отправки формы? Сейчас такое ощущение, что форма просто игнорирует скрипт.

Comment: Если убрать скрипт JQuery и указать форме напрямую обработчик, то все срабатывает правильно.

Comment: тогда добавь атрибут enctype="multipart/form-data" к form
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">

dataType в таком случае не нужен

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно определить событие по которому на `submit` будет навешено событие. Лучше на `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").submit(function(event) { 
    // ... 
  }
}
```