# Форма отправки заявки срабатывает только после перезагрузки

Tags: php, html, ajax

В чем может быть проблема, подскажите. Форма заявки срабатывает со второго раза: после первого клика по кнопке "Отправить" зачем-то выполняется перезагрузки страницы, после перезагрузки форма нормально отрабатывает и отправляет введенные в нее данные на почту.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function () { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function () {
            alert("Спасибо! Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение 20 минут!");
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Скрипт работает посредством файла mail.php, но в нем все нормально судя по всему.

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Вот форма отправки заявки и скрипты, менять местами скрипты пробовал, не помогает. Все скрипты нужные:

```
<form method="post"> 

                            <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="111">
                            <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="info@63site.ru">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заявка со страницы Контакты">

                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <label>Имя</label>
                                <input name="Имя" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <label>Телефон</label>
                                <input name="Телефон" type="tel" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input name="Email" type="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <label>Компания</label>
                                <input name="Компания" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <label>Сайт (если есть)</label>
                                <input name="Сайт" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="message-wrap">
                                <label>Комментарий</label>
                                <textarea name="Комментарий" rows="8"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="send-wrap">
                                <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Отправить</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/barba.js"></script>
    <script src="js/locomotive-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gsap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Ссылка страницу с проблемной формой
https://63site.ru/contact

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский код не будет работать без подключенного jQuery

Comment: Что увидел я. Есть форма, на ней есть кнопка с типом `submit`, на нее не навешано событие перехвата отправки формы, хотя судя по коду `javascript` что Вы привели это действие явно напрашивается. Таким образом у Вас по клику на кнопку происходит отправка формы с той самой перезагрузкой страницы, вместо того, чтобы отправить через `ajax` с помощью `javascript` . Что нужно сделать - навешать обработчик на событие `submit` формы - сделать в нем `preventDefault` для запрета отправки формы и далее отправлять данные формы через `ajax`

Comment: @lezhni да вы чтооо? А я то не знаааал

Comment: @phpBear у него return false стоит. Этого достаточно. У него проблема в другом

Comment: jquery подключен дважды, возможны конфликты.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я посмотрел рабочий код на который дана ссылка, а не тот , что приведен здесь. Они явно отличаются. В рабочем коде нет bind на submit.

Comment: Вопрос дублируется
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242067/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-php-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ajax-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8/1242142#1242142